# PyMongo - Update Based on ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a data in my `collection1` with `id`, `edit1`, `edit2`, `another1`, `another1` columns. I'm taking this data, doing some margins and outputing `DataFrame` with name `x1` with columns `id`, `edit1`, `edit2` where `id` for `x1` == `id` for `collection1` and `edit1`, `edit2` have changed values. 
I would like to `update` `edit1`, `edit2` columns data in `collection1` where `id` column match with `id` column from `x1` and leave other columns in `collection1` (`another1`, `another1`) as they are. I would like to ask how could I do this in effective way? Because I have a lot of data to matching.

I tried something like this, but it seems this doesn't work at all

```py
records_ = x1.to_dict(orient = 'records')
for record in records_ :
            self.db["collection1"].update_one({
                'id': record['id']
                },{
                '$set': {
                    'edit1': record['edit1'],
                    'edit2': record['edit2']
                }
                }, upsert=False)
```

Comment: Could you show how your sample collection looks like?

Comment: You might try a bulk operation